# CMake How to link libraries from a nested directory that need dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake

This is my project  structure

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Headers
│   ├── Network
│   └── OCR
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── ocr.cpp
│       └── ocr.hpp
├── main.cpp
```

My ./CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)  # Exports json file for lsp

project(ocrFoo)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# OpenCV
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
# X11
set(X11)
link_directories(/usr/lib/X11)
# Boost
set(BOOST_ROOT /home/user/Libraries/Boost/boost_1_82_0)
find_package(Boost 1.82.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
# Threads (Boost dependecy)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
# Subdirectories (Mine)
add_subdirectory(Headers/OCR)

# Boost
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/include/X11)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} X11)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Threads::Threads ocr)
```

The Headers/OCR/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(ocr ocr.cpp)
```

When i run `cmake` it runs smoothly without a problem.
But when i run `make` it throws me this error:

```
[ 25%] Building CXX object Headers/OCR/CMakeFiles/ocr.dir/ocr.cpp.o
In file included from /home/user/Projects/CPP/Real/Roulette/Headers/OCR/ocr.hpp:4,
                 from /home/user/Projects/CPP/Real/Roulette/Headers/OCR/ocr.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:48:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp: No such file or directory
   48 | #include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Headers/OCR/CMakeFiles/ocr.dir/build.make:76: Headers/OCR/CMakeFiles/ocr.dir/ocr.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:126: Headers/OCR/CMakeFiles/ocr.dir/all] Error
2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

And this is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Headers/OCR/ocr.hpp"


int main()
{
    cv::Mat image1, image2, diff_image;
    image1 = cv::imread("./unique_session_inactive.png");
    getROI(image1, true, true);
}
```

Doesn't my program has already linked the opencv libraries?
Because I have already linked them in the main ./CMakeLists.txt file.
Or should I also linked them from within the Headers/OCR/CMakeLists.txt? If this is the case then provide an example.

## I have tried the following:

Changed the Headers/OCR/CMakeLists.txt to:

```
project(ocr)

# OpenCV
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
# X11
set(X11)
link_directories(/usr/lib/X11)

# Also tried using PRIVATE with no sucess
target_include_directories(ocrFoo PUBLIC ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_LIBS} /usr/include/X11 X11)
target_link_libraries(ocrFoo PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS} X11)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ocr.cpp)
```

What am I missing since it's throwing the same error.

Comment: The `ocr` target is compiled separately. It does not inherit compiler flags or link flags from the targets it _is_ linked to.

Comment: I have edited the question showing what I have tried.

Comment: You left in `ocrFoo` as the target in your last edit. Yet your library is called `ocr`...

Comment: If i put ```ocr``` then i get this error ```CMake Error at Headers/OCR/CMakeLists.txt:10 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "ocr" which is not built by this
  project.```

Comment: Put the `add_library` statement *before* you try adding libraries or include directories.

Comment: It worked!. Thanks a lot. If you desire you can answer the question and I will upvoted & accept it. ;)